# Ruby Pattern Program Error while printing output

Tags: ruby

I had a working logic to print pyramid and square dynamically by accepting the number of rows from terminal. I am facing error after including "module,classes and begin-end block".

```
module PatternPrinting
  class Operation
    def input
      puts 'Enter the number of rows:'
      rows = Integer(gets.chomp)
      raise StandardError if rows <= 0 || rows > 10
      pyramid(rows)
      square(rows)
    rescue StandardError
      raise StandardError, 'Invalid Input, the entered value exceeds is not between 1-10 '
    end

  def pyramid(rows)
    rows.times do |n|
      print ' ' * (rows - n)
      puts '*' * (2 * n + 1)
    end
  end
  puts "Pyramid Rows: #{pyramid(rows)}"

  def square(rows)
    rows.times do |_n|
      puts '*' * 10
    end
  end
  puts "Sqaure Rows: #{square(rows)}"
end
end

begin
  res = PatternPrinting::Operation.new
  res.input
end
```

But I am facing error

```
pattern.rb:20:in `<class:Operation>': undefined local variable or method `rows' for PatternPrinting::Operation:Class (NameEr
ror)
        from ./pattern.rb:3:in `<module:PatternPrinting>'
        from ./pattern.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Comment: How to get the program working with the present logic?

Comment: @Shan_Boy : If your message refers to a line number, you should always indicate in your code listing, which is the affected line. You don't expect us to count the lines for you, do you? As for the error, you have a line `puts "Pyramid Rows: #{pyramid(rows)}"`. This line is executed while the class definition is going on. There is no variable (nor methode) named `rows`, and I don't see why you want to `puts` something during the time a class is being defined. There is no "present logic", because there is no logic in this program, so as a first step, just erase this line.

Answer (score 1):

`rows` is a local variable only available in the `input` method and nowhere else.  Once that method completed, the local variables are lost.

If you want data to be available to *all* methods of a class object, you need to use instance variables.

Do

```
@rows = Integer.get_chomp
```

And then do

```
@rows.times do |n|
```

and

```
@rows.times do |_n|
```

Comment: No your not.  You've got a different error. What is it?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing a basic concept in ruby.

- Read about ruby implicit and explicit receiver. https://www.reddit.com/r/ruby/comments/436d1m/what_is_the_difference_between_an_implicit_and/
- Local variable has method/function scoping. So, at 20 `rows` is not visible.
- Even though, let suppose your rows is accessible then also it should throw error coz, here implicit receiver self is your class `PatternPrinting`. `PatternPrinting` will try to invoke a method `pyramid` which is defined as class method https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#def-self-class-methods and your receiver `PatternPrinting` will not find the method and end up being calling method missing.
- I highly recommend take a look https://rubymonk.com/.

Comment: I think it's because method `pyramid` is *not* a class method.  It's not defined with a `self.` receiver nor within a `self << class` block.  So it's an instance method and won't throw an error. The receiver isn't `PatternPrinting`, it's an instance of `PatternPrinting::Operation` (`res = PatternPrinting::Operation.new`)